# It's in painting or on painting?

Tags: prepositions

Which is the correct sentence.
1. I could spend hours and hours in painting.
2. I could spend hours and hours on painting.

Comment: Hi Ling, welcome to ELU StackExchange! This particular question is trivial for native speakers and such questions are usually off-topic on this site; please consider the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) Stack Exchange instead.  In addition, ELU has a 'research requirement': you are supposed to have attempted to answer the question yourself using commonly available resources and are supposed to summarize this research, explaining why you still don't think you know the answer. The ELL SE also has a research requirement, but it is arguably less strict.

Comment: **I am so sorry sir, I didn't know about this**

Answer (score 4):

In this case the preposition is not necessary, You can say "I could spend hours and hours painting" just like you could say "I could spend hours and hours sleeping".

In a broader sense if you want to say "I could spend hours and hours **on a given task**", then it is correct to say "I could spend hours and hours on my homework". Versus if you wanted to say "I could spend hours and hours **in a given place**" then it is correct to say "I could spend hours and hours in the art studio".